# Wait for process to finish

Tags: java, batch-file

I am trying to convert something using this batch file. The batch file is called by java.
Problem is that the conversion is taking a while and the program just skips ahead resulting in a file not found error. I currently have built in a delay on java side using thread.sleep to make it work(very ugly).
The process state is 0 instantly so process.waitFor() isn´t working for me as is.
I need some way to make sure both the batch file and java are waiting until their subprocess finishes.

Java:

```java
Process conversion = runtime.exec("cmd /c start \"\" " 
                                        + scriptDirectory 
                                        + "convert.bat " 
                                        + filepath 
                                        + " " 
                                        + convertedFileName);

System.out.println("Conversion state: " + conversion.waitFor() + "!");
```

or:

```java
Process conversion = runtime.exec("cmd /c \\dltViewer\\dlt_viewer.exe -c " 
                                        + filepath 
                                        + " " 
                                        + convertedFileName);
```

Batch:

```
echo off
set back=%cd%
if exist %1 (
    echo %1
    /WAIT %back%\dltViewer\dlt_viewer.exe -c %1 %2
) else (
    echo ERROR: File not found!
    pause
)
exit
```

Comment: Why do you take the diversion over bat? Why not start dlt_viewer directly from your java code?

Comment: Also, your bat is not forwarding the exit code. You'd probably want to do that.

Comment: I did not now there was a way to run it directly

Comment: I will look into that

Comment: This: `/WAIT %back%\dltViewer\dlt_viewer.exe -c %1 %2` is not a valid command.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use a .bat file. Use Java’s [waitFor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor()) method instead:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(
    scriptDirectory + "\\dltViewer\\dlt_viewer.exe",
    "-c", filepath, convertedFileName);
builder.inheritIO();

Process conversion = builder.start();

int exitCode = conversion.waitFor();
if (exitCode != 0) {
    throw new IOException("Received exit code " + exitCode
        + " from command " + builder.command());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The process you start will take forever as it is likely blocked.
Rather than using waitFor, create a loop and use it to read all data from the process's STDOUT and STDERR streams. Also do not throw away that data. Instead place it either in a logfile or on system out so you can see whether the batch executes to your expectation.

The reason for this behaviour is documented in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html:

*By default, the created process does not have its own terminal or console. All its standard I/O (i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr) operations will be redirected to the parent process, where they can be accessed via the streams obtained using the methods getOutputStream(), getInputStream(), and getErrorStream(). The parent process uses these streams to feed input to and get output from the process. Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the process may cause the process to block, or even deadlock.*